# django query set not working in 1.8

Tags: sql, django

I just upgraded from 1.6 to 1.8 and I am finding a curious error.  I can't seem to get fields generated by a sql query to show up in the database rows, such as the following:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = models.User.objects.annotate(invited_count=Count('invitations'))
        qs = qs.extra({
        'average_invite_count': '(SELECT \
            (SELECT COUNT(ei.id) FROM events_invitation ei \
             WHERE ei.event_id IN (SELECT ee.id FROM events_event ee \
                WHERE ee.owner_id = users_user.id)) \
            / NULLIF(COUNT(ee.id), 0) FROM events_event ee \
            WHERE ee.owner_id = users_user.id)',
        })
        return qs

    def average_invite_count(self, obj):
        """
        Returns the count of created events.
        """
        return obj.average_invite_count
    average_invite_count.short_description = 'Created events'
    average_invite_count.admin_order_field = 'average_invite_count'

    list_display = ('phone_number', 'email', 'full_name', 'average_invite_count')
```

note: I believe there's an issue with the quotations on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

[From the Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

> ### Use this method as a last resort
>
> This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future. Use it only if you cannot express your query using other `queryset` methods. If you do need to use it, please file a ticket using the `QuerySet.extra` keyword with your use case (please check the list of existing tickets first) so that we can enhance the QuerySet API to allow removing extra(). We are no longer improving or fixing bugs for this method.

Support for `.extra` was pretty explicitly dropped in 1.8, and was frowned upon in 1.7 even.

I can only recommend you look at rewriting using the `annotation` queryset method and then `RawSQL` *only if necessary*. Django is pretty powerful now, so you can probably do what you need with [`aggregation`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/), [`F()` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) and [`ExpressionWrapper`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper).